# Sequences, sets and element position in the set.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I have a sequence Q with the length of N.

This is the fragment of this sequence:

`68 70 72 74 76 78 80`

The sequence has been divided into the sets of 4 elements each.

I know the first element of the set. And i need find position of the given element in the set:

For example: let take the set: 60 62 64 66,

I know that the first element is 60, then i was given element 64 and i need to find its position in the set. 
This is simple: 
`A(n) = A + (n - 1)*2 -> 64 = 60 + (n-1)*d thus n = 3`

I have found the position of the given element in the current set.

Now the hardest part! The sequence Q is still divided onto sets of 4, BUT it gets reset every 40 items:

`74 76 78 80 82 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56`

How would i find the position of the given element in the set of 4 in this case?

Any ideas?

P.S. this is a real life problem i need to solve to finish my programming task :)

**EDIT**

I also know the N (length of the sequence Q)

**EDIT**

Sequence can start with any even number

Comment: Group theory? This sounds more like combinatorics, no?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets reset every 40 items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "The sequence gets reset every $40$ items", so I assume that $Q$ is like $$P,P+2,P+4,P+6, \ldots ,P+2(M-1),P,P+2,P+4, \ldots $$ where $P=$ starting even number and $M=$the number of items of $Q$ between $2$ starting numbers, so the greatest number in the sequence will be $P+2(M-1)$.

Let $A$ be the first element of the $4$-item set (which is known), and $X$ the element, whose position $p_X$ is unknown. Then you have 
\begin{cases}
X > A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{X-A}{2}+1 \\
X < A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{2M+X-A}{2}+1 \\
\end{cases}
More generally speaking if we wish to know the formula for $p_X$ in a increasing sequence or in a decreasing sequence, let $\mu = \pm 1$ depending whether the sequence is increasing or decreasing; in particular $\mu = +1$ if we consider an increasing sequence and $\mu = -1$ when we manage a decreasing sequence $\ldots$ then the *general formula* will be:
\begin{cases}
\mu X > \mu A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{\mu (X-A)}{2}+1 \\
\mu X < \mu A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{\mu (X-A)+2M}{2}+1 \\
\end{cases}

Comment: Could you please tell me what is M? Lets take the set [80 82 42 44] i was given number 44, so the condition X<A is true, but im kinda stuck with M

Comment: If its the position of the element in this sequence then its unknown.

Comment: In this case $82 = P+2(M-1) = 42+2(21-1) \Rightarrow M = 21$, so the formula for this sequence is $X < A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{44+X-A}{2}$

Comment: I've edited the answer, so it can be understood more easily...or at least I hope so :)

Comment: OMG! Just checked! Genius! Thank you!

Comment: One more question! Can i apply the same rule for the same sequence that is decreasing? e.g in stead of sets like [80 82 42 44] i will be getting something like: [44 42 82 80]

Comment: Of course but the *formula* is slightly different: \begin{cases}
X < A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{A-X}{2}+1 \\
X > A \Rightarrow p_X= \frac{2M-X+A}{2}+1 \\
\end{cases}

Comment: Thank you! do you think if its possible to come up with one common formula for increasing and decreasing sequences? before your answer i was using Absolute(A-X)/2+1 which obviously doesn't work. Wel.. it does... but in some cases behavior is unpredictable

Comment: I'm adding the *general formula* to the answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13554/discussion-between-foga-and-rinchik)